# RenderPhysicalModel object was given and infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I'm trying to learn flutter and am failing to understand how to properly use their flexbox components. I have code here:

```
    return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SizedBox(
    width: 480,
    height: 120,
    child: Card(
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 466,
            height: 116,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 360,
                height: 96,
                child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
                          value: widget.complete,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              // TODO
                            });
                          }
                      ),
                      const SizedBox( width: 24 ),
                      Text(
                        widget.title,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ] ...continued
```

as you can see I've been forcing in as many constraints in the most ridiculous places possible in order to get rid of the `RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.` error.

Now I come from a modern html/css design philosophy where the minimum size for an element is the size of all its children combined and the maximum size is that of what its parent allows (in respect to siblings, padding, rendering lists etc). It seems like I have to 'adapt' some of that knowledge as my assumptions of '*Hm, this row/column will simply resize itself based off of its child* have caused me error after error after error.'

I have four questions:

1. Why, even after three generations of constraints, am I still getting an infinite size error?
2. Where did the infinite size come from? Who thought it was a good idea to make the default size for random components infinite?
3. Are columns and rows not a casual object I'm supposed to use whenever I see fit? Shouldn't they automatically constrain to the size of their children?
4. Which of the constraints are actually necessary for me to have, and which can I simply delete?

Columns and rows seemed to play nicely whenever I was reading the 'build a layout' tutorial, I don't know why they refuse to listen to anything I say now.

Comment: Do you have a scrollview or similar higher in the widget tree? I copied your example code and even with the various size constraints removed it functions fine (dartpad example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=69b9bcbd6a3a0598514d09e7a5cbab3c).

Comment: The code was giving me an error because of the scaffold I had at the top. This is not my root widget, and I guess you're supposed to only have one root scaffold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was giving me an error because of the scaffold I had at the top. This is not my root widget, and I guess you're supposed to only have one root scaffold